# Display block few seconds after page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a certain div that holds buttons at the bottom of my page. Above the div is a form with fields for user data.

```
<div>
  <form>
   <input >
   <input >
   <input >
  </form>
<div>
<div class="buttons-div">
   <button>ADD</button>
   <button>Cancel</button>
<div>
```

The problem is when the page loads, there is a delay in loading the form and the div holding the buttons loads first and the user can see it in the middle of the page for a few seconds. After the form is loaded, the div with the buttons assumes its proper place, at the bottom of the page.

I have tried to use ng-cloak as it is an angular app and place the .ng-cloak classes in my stylesheet. But none of that is working.

I tried to use

```
div.buttons-div {
    text-align: center;
    animation: fadein 11s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0;}
    to   { display: block;}
}
```

But I still don't think that is ideal. Instead of the fading effect, I would like to have it hidden for 10 seconds and just pop (display block). Replacing the opacity:0 above with display:none is not working. Is there a pure CSS solution for this?

Comment: use js `setTimeout()`

Comment: Use animation-delay to delay your display and if you want to popup, do you have the space reserved? using display block and none for animation with push the content besides it. using visibility: hidden will keep the space reserved but you will not be able to see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your css to this
to this:

```css
div.buttons-div { 
    opacity: 0; 
    text-align: center; 
    animation: fadein 1s; 
    animation-delay:10s; 
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
} 
@keyframes fadein { 
    from { opacity: 0; } /*Update because you asked for this numbers BUT i propose from 0 otherwise you are instantly seeing the div. */
    to { opacity: 1;} 
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons-div">My div</div>
```

As you can see you have to use http://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp the `animation-delay` instead of only the duration which is the `animation: fadein` in your case.

Comment: it actually shows up and disappears after a few seconds.

Comment: I updated my answer with the fill-mode. Check the snippet (run it).

Comment: thanks, but I had to change the above to the following 

div.action-bar-bottom {
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    animation: fadein 10s;
    animation-delay:1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0.9;}
    to   { opacity: 1;}
}

It now works

Comment: Glad I helped. Maybe you are not sharing the full code because snippet is working as you can see. Anyway glad that I helped. Maybe an acceptance? ;)

Comment: Update your answer to the following and I will accept. Thanks....  


div.action-bar-bottom {
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    animation: fadein 10s;
    animation-delay:1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0.9;}
    to   { opacity: 1;}
}

Comment: Done. Updated and running

Answer (score 1):

Try like this `opacity:1`   if you need ah delay use [**animation-delay**](http://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp)
.The `animation: fadein 11s;` in 11s is the animation duration .not a delay

**or**

try with single line shown below

**update:** apply intial `opacity=0`; and apply `forwards`.if you No need after hide just remove the `to   { opacity:0;}`

```css
    div.buttons-div {
            opacity:0;
            text-align: center;
            animation: fadein 3s 10s forwards;
          
        }
        
        @keyframes fadein {
            from { opacity: 0;}
            50%{opacity: 1;}
            to   { opacity:0;}
        }
```

```html
<div class="buttons-div">My div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question has already been answered I figured I would include a javascript option for someone who comes looking for a non-css-only solution later.

Add an `onload` to your body tag so that your buttons only show once the page is completely loaded.

```
<head>
     <script>
         function showButtons(){
              document.getElementById("buttons-div").style.display="block";
         }
     </script>
</head>
<body onload="showButtons();">
    <div>
       <form>
         <input >
         <input >
         <input >
       </form>
    <div>
    <div style="display:none;" id="buttons-div">
         <button>ADD</button>
         <button>Cancel</button>
    <div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can handle it form Onload Event.
we can't predict the time taking for to getting form field related content.
At the end of onLoad function you show the button div

Comment: We can't able to handle  this  scenario in CSS.
I'm saying When form field Onload event you can handle it to Show or Hide button div component

Comment: we cant predict time taking for form field content load